# Debating between different kinds of URL and see if one is more seo-friendly than other...

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting

So something like `domain.com\x\y\z\t` and `domain.com\x?var1=y&var2=z&var3=t` (var1, var2 and var3 will be replaced by legit words that make more sense).

**Which one is more SEO friendly?** For my purpose, second one seems more convenient, because it's easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is more SEO friendly and more user friendly. However, you can have your URLs appear like the first but act like the second using mod_rewite. Any basic [mod_rewrite tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewite%20tutorial) will show you how to do it.

Comment: SEO friendly, are we sure about this?  I'm pretty sure I read a google employee saying that URL format is completely irrelevant and it is a huge myth, but it does make the link more likely to be clicked as it is user friendly.

Comment: @Tom It's not the query string that is the issue. By using mod_rewrite you can order the keywords in the URL creating a hierarchy which helps to prioritize and organize the keywords. Those URLs also help to influence the anchor text of incoming links which is also very beneficial.

Comment: never thought about the anchor text from incoming links!  Great point, thanks!