# SEO benefits of URL as: www.example.com/category/subcategory/

Tags: url, seo, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [debating between different kinds of URL and see if one is more seo-friendly than other…](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3726/debating-between-different-kinds-of-url-and-see-if-one-is-more-seo-friendly-than)

Our SEO advisors are claiming that having our URLs in the form:

```
 www.example.com/category/subcategory/
```

leads to better ranking in the search engines, etc., but I'm not sure if that's true/valid.

Do others use this practice in their own websites?

The simpler alternative for us would be to do something like:

```
www.example.com/showcat.php?cat=Category-SubCategory
```

Comment: This is not quite programming related.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your SEO advisors are correct. You can actually use the [Apache Rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to translate that SEO-friendly URL into the alternative you would prefer.  By changing the desired URL structure to `www.example.com/categories/category/subcategory/`, you can do this in your .htaccess file:

RewriteRule ^categories/([^/]+)/([^/]+) showcat.php?cat=$1-$2

Basically when Apache receives the request with the SEO-friendly URL, it matches that line and calls the PHP file using the structure you prefer, automagically inserting the category names.

Almost every PHP CMS with SEO-friendly URLs uses mod_rewrite in some capacity.

Here's a helpful guide to get you started: http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: For more info about mod_rewrite, Google it or check out the links on the right under "Related" :)